# Convert Text Data Format to JSON

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have data from a Havnon Face Machine through SDK which returns the data in a text format as below

```
Return(result="success" dev_id="6714112110000298" total="4"
time="2013-03-12 20:20:46" id="1954" name="XYZ" workcode="0" status="0" authority="0X55" card_src="from_check"
time="2013-03-13 15:18:21" id="1954" name="XYZ" workcode="0" status="0" authority="0X55" card_src="from_check"
time="2013-03-13 15:30:14" id="8596" name="hari" workcode="0" status="0" authority="0X55" card_src="from_check"
time="2013-03-13 16:57:37" id="8596" name="hari" workcode="0" status="0" authority="0X55" card_src="from_check"
)2037-12-31 00:00:00
```

I am unable to parse it in a approprie manner the data resembles to JSON , is there a way to convert this type of data to JSON appropriate object

Comment: is this the exact string that it returns?

Comment: yes this is the exact string which it returns